# "INCORRECT_JSON_FORMAT userEvent" error in a Recommendations AI project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, user-event, google-cloud-recommendation

Does anyone have an idea what this error could mean?
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50TKY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/error-reporting?hl=fr#error-types) or [this](https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/error-reporting) documents:

```
INCORRECT_JSON_FORMAT: 
The JSON in the request is incorrectly formatted, such as a missing { bracket.
```